# Nesting SQL UDF in Spark/Databricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have a SQL UDF as shown below that returns a table:

```
REATE OR REPLACE TEMP FUNCTION pp_payments_agg()
RETURNS TABLE(invoice_number string, aging_bucket string,aging_bucket_text string, days_before_paid int, ref_date DATE)
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURN 
SELECT 
 invoice_number
,aging_bucket
,aging_bucket_text
,days_before_paid
,invoice_date AS ref_date
FROM default.payment_practices_invoice_data
WHERE (supplier_type LIKE 'DD'
AND supplier_name NOT LIKE '%AMEX%'
AND supplier_name NOT LIKE '%HSBC%')
UNION ALL
SELECT 
 payment_reference AS invoice_number
,aging_bucket
,aging_bucket_text
,days_before_paid
,paid_date AS ref_date
FROM default.payment_practices_payment_data
WHERE include = true;
```

I have another SQL UDF that I would like to return the min date from above table value function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP FUNCTION pp_min_date()
RETURNS DATE
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURN
(SELECT MIN(ref_date) mindate FROM pp_payments_agg());
```

This, however, is producing below error. Is it not possible to nest SQL UDF?

`could not resolve 'pp_payments_agg' to a table-valued function.; line 1 pos 7`

Simply running `SELECT MIN(ref_date) mindate FROM pp_payments_agg()` works but running it from a UDF produces above error.

Comment: Are you using Azure databricks or AWS?

Comment: Azure databricks

Answer (score 0):

If you try querying the `pp_min_date()` function after creating a temporary view on top of the table valued function so that it is materialized, it should work. You can try this below modification:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW temp_pp_payments_agg AS
SELECT MIN(ref_date) mindate 
FROM pp_payments_agg();

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP FUNCTION pp_min_date() RETURNS DATE 
LANGUAGE SQL 
RETURN ( SELECT mindate FROM temp_pp_payments_agg );
```